# Junit Mockito Test case giving method X giving ambiguous for the Type

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-data-jpa

I have a repo class with the following code

```
@Repository
public interface ShopComponentsFramesRepository extends JpaRepository<ShopComponentFrame, Long> {

    public List<ShopComponentFrame> findByComponentIdInAndShopId(Collection<Long> componentIdList,
            Collection<Long> shopIdList);

    public ShopComponentFrame findByComponentIdInAndShopId(Long componentId, Long shopId);

}
```

And I have a mockito junit test class with the following code, but the compiler is complaining -"***The method findByComponentIdInAndShopId(Collection, Collection) is ambiguous for the type ShopComponentsFramesRepository***"

```
@Test
    public void testRequestReceivingDropdownElements() {
        ReceivingDropdownsView sampleDropdownsView = getReceivingDropdownsSample();
        when(authorityManager.retrieveAuthorities(USER_NAME)).thenReturn(getSampleAuthoritiesView());
        when(shopComponentFrameConverter.convertToView(anyObject())).thenReturn(getComponentFrame());
        when(shopComponentsFramesRepository.findByComponentIdInAndShopId(anyObject(), anyObject()))
                .thenReturn(getShopComponentFrameList());
        when(shopComponentsFramesRepository.findByComponentIdInAndShopId(anyLong(), anyLong()))
                .thenReturn(getShopComponentFrame());
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure but try replacing Long in second overloaded method with long. Long is still an Object like Collection and might be causing the ambiguity. Just a speculation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the line

```
when(shopComponentsFramesRepository.findByComponentIdInAndShopId(anyObject(), anyObject()))
            .thenReturn(getShopComponentFrameList());
```

with

```
when(shopComponentsFramesRepository.findByComponentIdInAndShopId(anyCollectionOf(Long.class), anyCollectionOf(Long.class)))
            .thenReturn(getShopComponentFrameList());
```

so that Mockito can tell which of the two versions of the method you're trying to stub.

Alternatively, use different names for the two methods.